# Troubles installing paho-mqtt on small linux board

Tags: python-3.x, pip, mqtt

I'm trying to experiment with using MQTT from Python3 running on a small ARM based SBC (think Raspberry Pi or BeagleBone). I tried installing `paho-mqtt` using the following:

```
apt-get install python3-pip
pip3 install paho-mqtt
```

But that errored out:

```
 Collecting paho-mqtt
  Downloading paho-mqtt-1.2.tar.gz (49kB)
    100% |################################| 51kB 170kB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    ImportError: No module named 'setuptools'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-isz18gxf/paho-mqtt/
```

Primarily, what do I need to do to get this to load?

Secondarily, if there is a better alternative for a python3 mqtt library, I would love to hear about it.

UPDATE:

The complete solution that I needed to use to get this particularly package to work was

```
apt-get install python3-pip
apt-get install python3-setuptools
apt-get install python3-wheel
pip3 install paho-mqtt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your **paho-mqtt** needs **setuptools** to be installed first and it looks like you dont have it on your distro...

do:

> sudo apt-get install python-setuptools